# Flutter - Which widget is the most optimized for live scaling Image with 0 to 1 values?

Tags: flutter

I want to animate a certain widget as long as the music is playing. The data is obtained continuously from a callback within my code.

```
void _onMusicFFTData(double normalized){
// TODO: somehow scale image widget with the normalized value
}
```

My values received from this callback are already interpolated, so I do not want any kind of Curve usage. I want to scale a certain image directly with the values received from the callback. I saw that there is ScaleTransition with scale property.

```
ScaleTransition(scale: ,)
```

I could not see any ways to feed normalized 0 to 1 values to this widget. It only takes predefined animation such as

```
 _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
      vsync: this,
    )..repeat(reverse: true);
    _animation = CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _controller,
      curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
    );
```

I can basically use SetState and use a Transform.scale but I dont think thats the right way to animate as it feels unintuitive and more like a workaround. Which widget would help me scale my image widget with 0 to 1 live values during runtime?

Comment: `ScaleTransition(scale: controller,)` and `_onMusicFFTData(double normalized) => controller.value = 1 + normalized;`

Comment: can you explain further? why value = 1 + normalized

Comment: use `ScaleTransition(scale: controller, child: ...)` as a widget and your callback would look like `_onMusicFFTData(double normalized) => controller.value = 1 + normalized;` ok remove `1` if you want - its up to you how you want to scale it

Comment: i was wondering what setting value does but I read the documentation. This seems to do the job